# How to use unattended os install in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I know that in the latest version of VirtualBox, 5.2, a feature was added: ["(Automatic) Unattended Guest OS Install (aka Easy Install in VMware)](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/5810)."

But, how can we use the feature, for example, to install Ubuntu? I can't understand. There aren't any new menu items or checkboxs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The details can be found in the [VBox user manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#basic-unattended); it involves the commands

```bsh
VBoxManage createvm ...    # Optionally using the GUI
VBoxManage unattended ...
VBoxManage startvm ...
```

Comment: That link only talks about unattended installation of VirtualBox itself, not about unattended installation of VMs

Comment: The correct link is https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#basic-unattended

Comment: @RafaelEyng Thanks, I've adapted the chapter number to the new one.